# XQuery node is sequence

Tags: xquery, node-set, functx

Is `is-node-in-sequence-deep-equal` in XQuery? I'm wondering because I've seen the function at [xqueryfunctions.com](http://www.xqueryfunctions.com/xq/functx_is-node-in-sequence-deep-equal.html), but I'm not being able to use it.

Answer (score 2):

That function is part of the FunctX XQuery library. There are two methods to use this function:

1. You [download the whole library](http://www.xqueryfunctions.com/xq/download.html) (select the download which corresponds to your version of XQuery), save it in the same directory as your XQuery program/file and then import the module in your XQuery file, e.g.:

   ```
   import module namespace functx = "http://www.functx.com" at "functx-1.0-doc-2007-01.xq";

   (: Insert your code here and call the is-node-in-sequence-deep-equal function as seen below :)

   functx:is-node-in-sequence-deep-equal($node, $seq)
   ```
2. Instead of downloading the whole library with all functions  you can also simply copy paste the specific function which you need as shown on the [page you linked to](http://www.xqueryfunctions.com/xq/functx_is-node-in-sequence-deep-equal.html):

   ```
   declare namespace functx = "http://www.functx.com"; 
   declare function functx:is-node-in-sequence-deep-equal 
     ( $node as node()? ,
       $seq as node()* )  as xs:boolean {

      some $nodeInSeq in $seq satisfies deep-equal($nodeInSeq,$node)
    } ;

   (: Insert your code here and call the 'is-node-in-sequence-deep-equal' function as seen below :)

   functx:is-node-in-sequence-deep-equal($node, $seq)
   ```

In both examples you simply replace `$node` and `$seq` with your variables.